# CSS Scale Image on Hover, Transparent Layer and Text on Top

Tags: css, hover, scale, layer

I have a slight problem adding features to HTML block in CSS. Here is how it is supposed to work:

1. *User hovers over the block*;
2. *Background image scales to 1.25 in 0.4 seconds*;
3. *Simultaneously the whole block is overlayed by semi-transparent grey block with text in the middle*.

The problem is as follows: On hover not only *image increases*, but also the *text*. I do realise that probably all descendats scale to 1.25; however, only **image should scale**, while **text remains the same size in the middle of semi-transparent layer**. Help me to solve it, please.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="image-block">
        <div class="layer">
            <span>Whatever</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-family: sans-serif;
}
.container {
height: 20em;
width: 20em;
overflow: hidden;
}
.image-block {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background: url(http://a1.dspnimg.com/data/l/467928107631_M5V8zyVM_l.jpg) no-repeat center center;
background-size: cover;
transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.layer {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
opacity: 0;
}
.image-block:hover .layer {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
opacity: 1;
}
.container:hover .image-block {
transform: scale(1.25);
}
```

And jsfiddle link also: http://jsfiddle.net/vorontsov/kL8Lb8pm/10/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kL8Lb8pm/11/

Comment: @Paulie_D, Are you a magician or something? Great thanks! :)
Can you explain a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's with the text centered. What Paulie_D and I did to make the only the background image resize is change your `transform: scale(1.25);` to `background-size: 125%;` on `.container:hover .image-block`. You also need to change `background-size: cover;` to `background-size: 100%;` on `.image-block`.

Example:

```
   .image-block {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background: url(http://a1.dspnimg.com/data/l/467928107631_M5V8zyVM_l.jpg) no-repeat center center;
        background-size: 100%; /* This line was changed */
        transition: all 0.4s ease;
    }

    .container:hover .image-block {
        background-size: 125%; /* This line was changed */
    }
```

To vertically and horizontally center align the text you need to add:

```
    .layer {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
        opacity: 0;
        text-align: center;
        display: table; /* this line was added */
    }

    /* This whole block was added */
    .layer span {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

Here is a full working example:

```css
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: 0;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }
        .container {
            display: table;
            height: 20em;
            width: 20em;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .image-block {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            background: url(http://a1.dspnimg.com/data/l/467928107631_M5V8zyVM_l.jpg) no-repeat center center;
            background-size: 100%;
            transition: all 0.4s ease;
        }
        .layer {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
            opacity: 0;
            text-align: center;
            display: table;
        }
        .layer span {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        .image-block:hover .layer {
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
            opacity: 1;
        }
        .container:hover .image-block {
            background-size: 125%;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="image-block">
        <div class="layer">
            <span>Whatever</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's even more than I asked for. Thank you very much! When I asked to elaborate a bit, I just meant to explain why scale is not working and such common thing as background-size holds. Anyway, merci.